# MIPS quicksort an array

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to convert a piece of "C" code to MIPS Assembly language for learning purpose. I wrote the MIPS code, but somewhere I am doing wrong and not getting the desired output. When I ran the program, it is showing completely different numbers. Please correct me where I am doing wrong?

C code:

```html
void swap(int array[], int a, int b) {
     int t = array[a];
     array[a] = array[b];
     array[b] = t;
 }

int partition (int arr[], int low, int high) {
    int pivot = arr[high]; // pivot
    int i = (low - 1); // Index of smaller element
     for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++) {
         if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++; // increment index of smaller element
            swap(arr, i, j);
            }
      }
    swap(arr, i + 1, high);
    return (i + 1);
}


void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) {
     if (low < high) {
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
       quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
     }
 }
```

MIPS written:

```html
.data # Defines variable section of an assembly routine.
array: .word 12,1,13,10,3,5,2,1 # Define a variable named array as a word (integer) array.

.text # Defines the start of the code section for the program .
.globl main
main:
la $t0, array # Moves the address of array into register $t0.
addi $a0, $t0, 0 # Set argument 1 to the array.
addi $a1, $zero, 0 # Set argument 2 to (low = 0)
addi $a2, $zero, 7 # Set argument 3 to (high = 7, last index in array)
jal quickSort # Call quick sort

li $v0, 10 # Terminate program run and
syscall # Exit

### My code start from here
quickSort: 
  addi $sp, $sp, -20 #Make room on stack for  5 registers 
  sw $ra, 16($sp) #save return address on memory
  sw $a0, 12($sp) #save a0
  sw $a1, 8($sp) #save a1
  sw $a2, 4($sp) #save a2
  sw $s0 , 0($sp) #save $s0

  slt $t1, $a1, $a2   #t1=1 --> low < high, otherwise 0
  beq $t1, $zero, Exit #if low > high, branch to Exit 
  jal partition   #call  if low < high
  
  move $s0, $v0   #load partition output to s0
  addi $a2, $s0, -1  #a2 = pi - 1
  jal quickSort   #calling quickSort

  addi $a1, $s0, 1  #a1 = pi + 1
  lw $a2, 4($sp)   #loading original a2
  jal quickSort   #calling quickSort

Exit: 
  lw $s0, 0($sp)
  lw $a2, 4($sp)
  lw $a1, 8($sp)
  lw $a0, 12($sp)
  lw $ra, 16($sp)
  addi $sp, $sp, 20 
  jr $ra



 partition:
   addi $sp, $sp, -24
   sw $ra, 20($sp)
   sw $s0, 16($sp)
   sw $s1, 12($sp)
   sw $s2, 8($sp)
   sw $s3, 4($sp)
   sw $s4, 0($sp)

   sll $t1, $a2, 2  #t1 = 4 * high
   add $t1, $a0, $t1 #t1 = *arr + t1
   lw $s0, 0($t1)  #s0, pivot = arr[high]
   addi $s1, $a1, -1 #i=low -1
   add $s2, $a1, $zero #j=low
   add $s3, $a2, $zero #s3=high

   forloop:

    addi $t2, $s3, -1  #t2 = high - 1
    slt $t3, $t2, $s2  #t3=1 --> j> high - 1
    bne $t3, $zero, Exit1 #if j>high -1 branch to Exit 1

    sll $t4, $s2,2   #t4 = 4j
    add $t4, $a0, $t4  #t4 = *arr + 4j
    lw $s4, 0($t4)   #s4 = arr[j]

    slt $t5, $s0, $s4  #t5=1 --> arr[j] > pivot
    beq $t5, $zero, Exit2 #if arr[j] <= pivot, branch to Exit2
    addi $s2, $s2, 1  #j++
    j forloop    #jump to forloop

    Exit2:
     addi $s1, $s1, 1 #i++
     move $a1, $s1  #a1 = i 
     move $a2, $s2  #a2 = j 
     jal swap    #calling swap
     addi $s2, $s2, 1 #j++
     j forloop   #calling forloop

   Exit1:  
     addi $s1, $s1, 1 #i=i+1
     move $a1, $s1  #a1=i+1
     move $a2, $s3  #a2=high
     jal swap    #calling swap
     move $v0, $a1  #return i+1

    lw $ra, 20($sp)
    lw $s0, 16($sp)
    lw $s1, 12($sp)
    lw $s2, 8($sp)
    lw $s3, 4($sp)
    lw $s4, 0($sp)
    jr $ra

 swap:  
   addi $sp, $sp, -8   # Make room for two elements
   sw $ra, 4($sp)    # Save return address
   sw $s5, 0($sp)    # Save s5 register

   sll $t6, $a1, 2    #t6 = a*4
   add $t6, $a0, $t6   #t6 = *a0 + 4a
   lw $s5, 0($t6)    #t = array[a]

   sll $t7, $a2, 2    #t7 = b*4
   add $t7, $a0, $t7   #$t7 = *a0 + 4b
   lw $t8, 0($t7)    #t8 = array[b]
   sw $t8, 0($t6)    #array[a] = array[b]
   sw $s5, 0($t7)    #array[b] = t 

   lw $s5, 0($sp)
   lw $ra, 4($sp)
   addi $sp, $sp, 8
   jr $ra
```

Comment: *"When I ran the program"* - this. You don't write 50 lines of asm, and then just run it.. you add 2-5 lines more, then use the debugger to single step over each instruction, checking if everything does what it was intended and nothing else.

Comment: Your C is not human-readable.  Indent it properly.  But more importantly, show what exactly you *are* getting, vs. what the expected result is, to make this a [mcve].  Even better, use the debugger built-in to MARS or SPIM to single-step your code and find out which instruction isn't doing what you hoped.  (e.g. which branch is going the wrong way.)  You did at least comment your asm, but there's too much of it to easily read through by hand and verify all the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the MIPS program for the quick sort. Taken from: https://github.com/bharathkarumudi/MIPS/blob/master/quicksort.asm

```
#------------------------------------#
# Authored by: Bharath Karumudi     #
# Purpose Quicksort in MIPS         #
#------------------------------------#

.data # Defines variable section of an assembly routine.
array: .word 12,15,10,5,7,3,2,1 # Define a variable named array as a word (integer) array.
# After your program has run, the integers in this array
# should be sorted.
.text # Defines the start of the code section for the program .
.globl main

main:
la $t0, array # Moves the address of array into register $t0.
addi $a0, $t0, 0 # Set argument 1 to the array.
addi $a1, $zero, 0 # Set argument 2 to (low = 0)
addi $a2, $zero, 7 # Set argument 3 to (high = 7, last index in array)
jal quicksort # Call quick sort
li $v0, 10 # Terminate program run and
syscall # Exit


swap:               #swap method

addi $sp, $sp, -12  # Make stack room for three

sw $a0, 0($sp)      # Store a0
sw $a1, 4($sp)      # Store a1
sw $a2, 8($sp)      # store a2

sll $t1, $a1, 2     #t1 = 4a
add $t1, $a0, $t1   #t1 = arr + 4a
lw $s3, 0($t1)      #s3  t = array[a]

sll $t2, $a2, 2     #t2 = 4b
add $t2, $a0, $t2   #t2 = arr + 4b
lw $s4, 0($t2)      #s4 = arr[b]

sw $s4, 0($t1)      #arr[a] = arr[b]
sw $s3, 0($t2)      #arr[b] = t 


addi $sp, $sp, 12   #Restoring the stack size
jr $ra          #jump back to the caller



partition:          #partition method

addi $sp, $sp, -16  #Make room for 5

sw $a0, 0($sp)      #store a0
sw $a1, 4($sp)      #store a1
sw $a2, 8($sp)      #store a2
sw $ra, 12($sp)     #store return address

move $s1, $a1       #s1 = low
move $s2, $a2       #s2 = high

sll $t1, $s2, 2     # t1 = 4*high
add $t1, $a0, $t1   # t1 = arr + 4*high
lw $t2, 0($t1)      # t2 = arr[high] //pivot

addi $t3, $s1, -1   #t3, i=low -1
move $t4, $s1       #t4, j=low
addi $t5, $s2, -1   #t5 = high - 1

forloop: 
    slt $t6, $t5, $t4   #t6=1 if j>high-1, t7=0 if j<=high-1
    bne $t6, $zero, endfor  #if t6=1 then branch to endfor

    sll $t1, $t4, 2     #t1 = j*4
    add $t1, $t1, $a0   #t1 = arr + 4j
    lw $t7, 0($t1)      #t7 = arr[j]

    slt $t8, $t2, $t7   #t8 = 1 if pivot < arr[j], 0 if arr[j]<=pivot
    bne $t8, $zero, endfif  #if t8=1 then branch to endfif
    addi $t3, $t3, 1    #i=i+1

    move $a1, $t3       #a1 = i
    move $a2, $t4       #a2 = j
    jal swap        #swap(arr, i, j)

    addi $t4, $t4, 1    #j++
    j forloop

    endfif:
    addi $t4, $t4, 1    #j++
    j forloop       #junp back to forloop

endfor:
    addi $a1, $t3, 1        #a1 = i+1
    move $a2, $s2           #a2 = high
    add $v0, $zero, $a1     #v0 = i+1 return (i + 1);
    jal swap            #swap(arr, i + 1, high);

    lw $ra, 12($sp)         #return address
    addi $sp, $sp, 16       #restore the stack
    jr $ra              #junp back to the caller

quicksort:              #quicksort method

addi $sp, $sp, -16      # Make room for 4

sw $a0, 0($sp)          # a0
sw $a1, 4($sp)          # low
sw $a2, 8($sp)          # high
sw $ra, 12($sp)         # return address

move $t0, $a2           #saving high in t0

slt $t1, $a1, $t0       # t1=1 if low < high, else 0
beq $t1, $zero, endif       # if low >= high, endif

jal partition           # call partition 
move $s0, $v0           # pivot, s0= v0

lw $a1, 4($sp)          #a1 = low
addi $a2, $s0, -1       #a2 = pi -1
jal quicksort           #call quicksort

addi $a1, $s0, 1        #a1 = pi + 1
lw $a2, 8($sp)          #a2 = high
jal quicksort           #call quicksort

 endif:

lw $a0, 0($sp)          #restore a0
lw $a1, 4($sp)          #restore a1
lw $a2, 8($sp)          #restore a2
lw $ra, 12($sp)         #restore return address
addi $sp, $sp, 16       #restore the stack
jr $ra              #return to caller
```

Comment: This code is giving wrong answer for array with certain negative elements in it.